# Angular 5 changing my original request object while intercepting

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am trying to add some new header by intercepting all the request. Below is my code for intercepting

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { post } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';

@Injectable()
export class WhypinsHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('data1', 'somedata'), method: req.method });
    console.log(authReq);
    return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

}

Now my actual request object contain a json string in the body of the original request. But after doing clone of the original request and added new header information while sending the request object the requested method converting from POST method to OPTIONS. And the body json object is removed after doing clone. Anybody have any idea about this issue.

Comment: This is a [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. Specifically, what you’re seeing is known as a *preflight check*.

Comment: Kindly help me, how to solve this issue.

Comment: i am not quite sure if it is a cors issue as pointed by one of the devs here , i might be wrong but i guess `This is because HTTPParams is immutable, and its API methods do not cause object mutation.`

Comment: For more information if i'm not changing the actual request and directly calling the next.handle(req) all working fine. Problem occurs when i  do any changes in the request object before calling handle method

Comment: You only can add whos headers that your server accepts